# Why do I have to use parantheses in (x > 0) & (x < 2) to avoid "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous"?

Tags: python, numpy

Having:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.ndarray([0,1,2])
```

This doesn't work:

```
x > 0 & x < 2
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

This works:

```
(x > 0) & (x < 2)
Out[32]: array([False,  True, False])
```

So maybe the reason is operator precedence. But all of these work as well:

```
((x > 0) & x) < 2
Out[33]: array([ True,  True,  True])

(x > (0 & x)) < 2
Out[34]: array([ True,  True,  True])

x > ((0 & x) < 2)
Out[35]: array([False, False,  True])

x > (0 & (x < 2))
Out[36]: array([False,  True,  True])
```

Then why does the original expression not work, if any order of operator execution would work? Is it because choosing one of them is ambiguous? But then the exception message is misleading?

Comment: The error I'm getting on Python 3.11 with the same code is: `TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: Interesting, seems to be related to python version then, with 3.8 I get your error as well. Above I used 3.7

Comment: DON"T use `np.ndarray`.  You want `a = np.array([0,1,2])`

Comment: The `bitwise` error is produced when `x` is the (0,1,2) shaped array produced by `ndarray`.  We don't get that with the (3,) shaped `np.array([0,1,2])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `x > 0 & x < 2` is more like `(x > (0 & x)) and ((0 & x) < 2)`, and the error is raised for the operation `and`.

I believe it's caused by that `&` will be calculated before comparison, and python has a syntactic sugar to translate `x > y < z` into `(x > y) and (y < z)`.

Comment: Which means that the original condition can be `0 < x < 2`

Comment: @matszwecja `(x > 0) and (x < 2)` -> `(0 < x) and (x < 2)` -> `0 < x < 2`

Comment: @Caleth Nevermind, for some reason I thought of bitwise OR not AND.